# Difference between previous and current month in Power Pivot

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerpivot

I have a question about DAX function which would help me to find difference between last two months for each of the products.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G6Jki.png)
Unfortunately I cannot wrap my head around time intelligence functions which could be used here, since all the examples which I found do differ from mine. I am wondering whether there is function at all for this purpose, so once I add March data it will will be automatically calculating difference between February and March.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m1RIq.png)
Thank you in advance for any advice you could give.

Comment: You are adding new month's data as a new column? If yes, first question is.. why?

Comment: because power pivot table needs to be updated every month, I don't have data for the rest of the year